# How to use .htaccess to switch content to display under maintenance message

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to have `/blog` directory on my application to have an instance of WordPress installed there. Currently `/blog` does takes me there, but I do want to know and have control, instead of directory how to read from `routes.php`.

There can be many use cases for it as `blog` directory is under maintenance or its down, in that case a simple change so it starts reading `/blog` from `routes.php`.

I am not much expert of '.htaccess' file but can we do from it?

Answer (score 0):

if your CI application use the default routes configuration, then /blog will make CI try to load blog controller and index action, if it can't find them. you'll get 404 page not found error.
try to config the /blog in your web server configuration. add /blog block then apply wordpress server config there. make sure that request will find /blog location block before the / location block.
in nginx:

```
location /blog {
    # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
    # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

# then your ci / location
location / {
    # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

Comment: i am using apache